# ESLint Airbnb WebStorm coding standards

Tags: javascript, webstorm, eslint

I have entered my ESLint on base of the Airbnb coding standards and the ESLint itself is working fine. However I still have one error that occurs when using the WebStorm autoformatting function. It expects 2 spaces but it formats to 0 spaces.

It is now like this:

```
{!lite &&
<div
  className={cn(
```

It should be like:

```
{!lite &&
  <div
    className={cn(
```

Anyone that knows which setting I should use for this?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently possible, please follow [WEB-25338](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25338) for updates